# How to access value from this object

Tags: javascript, object

How to access value from this object:

```
{
    "user_voted_1": "1",
    "user_voted_2": "1",
    "user_voted_3": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dot notation (`object.property`):

```
console.log(data.user_voted_1);
```

Comment: this log undefined... Key is a string

Comment: I have this app live on this link [link](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Digital-Production/489726024420729?sk=app_292141147653749)

Comment: Um, that link isn't very helpful - it's definitely not clear how it relates to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is

```
var data = {
  "user_voted_1": "1",
  "user_voted_2": "1",
  "user_voted_3": "1"
};
```

You can access the properties with one of these patterns:

```
var x = data.user_voted_1;    // x = "1"
var y = data["user_voted_2"]; // y = "1"
```

On a side note, if you're having difficulty with this, I recommend reading some tutorials on Javascript before continuing; otherwise you're likely to run into some real problems...